# Can (La)TeX be a compelling technology for the humanities, journalism, and other non-technical disciplines?

Tags: tex-core

All over the web, I see how LaTeX has been successful as a way of describing mathematical notation, which makes it pretty easy to argue that it is a compelling technology for science, technology, engineering, math, and other highly technical fields.  For these fields, the complexity of mathematical notations makes the technicality of writing manuscripts in LaTeX acceptable.

This is nice, but it is not interesting for my personal document preparation and typesetting needs.  I am very interested in the idea of a very high quality, libre/free typesetting technology for non-technical writing, but the big obstacle I see is that the this level of technicality for STEM authoring is far too high for anything but a niche presence in the humanities, journalism, and other non-technical fields.

Can LaTeX or a TeX-based workflow be used for non-technical scholarly writing at an appropriately accessible level?   If so, are there examples of widely used TeX-based workflows?  If not, what would the best libre/free document preparation and typesetting systems be?

Comment: LaTeX is still the way to go. The most widely accepted solution is unfortunately MS Word.

Comment: Okay, okay, fine. `s/most widely accepted/most widely accepted among those with working brains/`, then. :P

Comment: Cuneiform inscription. Since 4000 BC.

Comment: If the journals don’t support TeX-based submissions in the first place, your collaborators can’t be expected to understand some TeX format, and you’re going to publish predominantly books, then [Context](http://wiki.contextgarden.net) is orders of magnitude more convenient for the humanities than Latex.
Currently, various related parts of Context are [being overhauled](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2013/075936.html) under an academic grant, so right now is the time to post feature requests on the [mailing list](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Mailing_Lists#Mailing_lists).

Comment: @KeksDose touche.

Comment: I don't think this is on topic.

Comment: @phg Cool, I'll look into Context.

Comment: @egreg: The question might be taken as "Is Latex right for my authoring needs?" which is on topic, but a bit too broad.

Comment: I could try editing the qn to help avoid it being either off-topic or overbroad, but the edit would be quite heavy and involve some guessing as to what you are after.  Should I try?

Comment: @CharlesStewart Sure, why not.

Comment: @phg -- Is there a place to follow development vis-à-vis the critical edition stuff other than the mailing list?  I'm not a ConTeXt user, but if the format becomes at least as usable for (complex) critical editions as `eledmac`/`eledpar`, I will learn ConTeXt!

Comment: @jon If you want to stay up to date regarding Context, I’m afraid  the mailing list is the only canonical source for news (apart from the [commit log](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/shortlog/refs/heads/origin), of course!).
The list allows AFAIR unregistered users to post.
If you send a mail asking for a status update every quarter, I’m confident Thomas, Hans, or Luigi will give you a brief summary.
Other than that, many new features appear to be revealed at the yearly [Context meetings](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/).